# Do multiple shower heads require multiple shower valves?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I'm working with a home builder to have two shower heads in a master bath shower. The builder proposes have two shower valves, one per head. Is this recommended/required or is the builder just trying to charge me more for another part?

Comment: Where are the two heads going to go?  Right next to each other?  On adjacent walls?  Rain head on the ceiling?  I have two heads and two valves and I really wouldn't want it any other way.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Two shower heads next to each other? "Hydra" monster. :)

Comment: Some like it hot. Without two valves, co-ed showers won't be fun for one of you. One thing though, if an extra valve will require a larger pipe, it'll take longer to get hot in normal use. I've had two before (nothing beats it), but it was fed in 3/4s; almost took 5min to get hot. - "require" ? IMO, absolutely.

Comment: I have a Hansgrohe trim with integrated diverter and mixing valve. Works great for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want both shower heads to be on at the same time everytime you take a shower, then yes you need 2 controls. If you don't care if both head are on, then one control will be fine.

Comment: And you can always add a shower head shut off valve..

Comment: And if both shower heads are on at the same time, they possibly won't have as good a flow as just one, unless the place has very good water pressure.

Comment: @JACK Shower-head shut off valves can cause cross-over problems (hot water flowing out of cold taps and vice versa). You're shutting off the flow *downstream* of the hot/cold mixing of the main shower cartridge. Think twice before installing this bullshit, especially if you live in a condo building.

Comment: if you only cut one shower head off at a time there should be no problem.

Comment: @Kaz I've been installing them in our single family homes for 55 years and love them... saved a lot of water.

Answer (score 2):

I have two heads in the master, I don't remember any charge but I guess there was. You just add inexpensive shut-offs on each head , works fine. BUT , in the US , regulations require that these shut-off valves leak, so if you have a head turned off ,it will still drip. We usually have both on at the same time. It did take a couple trips to the "big box" store and one trip to the plumbing store to find out that these shut-off are required to leak ( in US).